# Pointer casting in Fortran

Tags: fortran

For interoperability with the C programming language I need to cast a pointer in Fortran. Essentially, I like to achieve in Fortran what looks the following in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int  n = 100;
    long ptr;

    ptr = (long) &n;
    printf("ptr: %ld\n", ptr);
}
```

(`long` used for simplicity here, `int_ptr_t` should be preferred.) The example outputs:

```
ptr: 140737488349460
```

But trying the same in Fortran using `transfer()` leads to something different:

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer, target :: n = 100
    integer(kind=8) :: ptr

    ptr = transfer(loc(n), ptr)
    print '(a, i0)', 'ptr: ', ptr
end program main
```

Output:

```
ptr: 6296120
```

One could also use the appropriate ISO C binding types and functions, with the very same result:

```
program main
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer(kind=c_int), target :: n = 100
    integer(kind=c_intptr_t)    :: ptr

    ptr = transfer(c_loc(n), ptr)
    print '(a, i0)', 'ptr: ', ptr
end program main
```

Why is `loc(n)`/`c_loc(n)` not returning a similiar memory address?

(Examples have been compiled with GCC 9 and GNU Fortran 9.)

Comment: If you are doing this for interoperability with C, why aren't you using the standard interoperability features?

Comment: Actually, it makes no difference.

Comment: From compiling the the two, and looking at the `objdump -D` output for each... In the Fortran version, the pointer is to a value stored in the `.data` section.  In the C version, the pointer is to a value that has been pushed onto the stack.

Comment: There is no reason a priori that the Fortran and C executables would store the first integer of the main program at the same memory location. Maybe you could explain what you are ultimately trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran only stores allocatable variables on the stack. Therefore, the variable of which the stack address is wanted must be declared as pointer or allocatable:

```
program main
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer(kind=c_int), pointer :: n => null()
    integer(kind=c_intptr_t)     :: ptr

    allocate (n)
    n = 100
    ptr = transfer(c_loc(n), ptr)
    print '(a, i0)', 'ptr: ', ptr
end program main
```

Result:

```
ptr: 34366292000
```

Comment: Perhaps if you told us what you're actually *trying* to achieve, we might be able to help. For now, it seems like you're just providing memory addresses and declaring that it's not working the way you expect.